# ActiveRecord: Order table based on the average of an association's column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am building a system for job seekers to track jobs their interested in using Rails. I want to rank companies based on the user's level of interest in the company as determined by averaging the user-declared 'level of interest' in each job posted by the company. So, for example, Wal Mart might post 3 jobs, and the user would submit their level of interest for each of those jobs, and we'd calculate the overall interest in Wal Mart by averaging those 3 levels of interest. There will be several companies with several jobs.

My database has 2 tables: Companies and Jobs, where a company has many jobs and a job has one company. A job also has a 'level_of_interest' attribute which should be used to calculate the user's overall interest in a company.

Is there a way to do this using just ActiveRecord methods? My current solution is:

```
Job.group('company_id').average(:level_of_interest)
```

And then using Ruby to pull the companies out of the resulting hash, but I think there's probably a way to do it purely with ActiveRecord.

DB is PG, fwiw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Company.select('companies.id, avg(jobs.level_of_interest)')
       .joins(:jobs)
       .group('companies.id')
       .order('avg(jobs.level_of_interest) desc')
```

Comment: I get the logic of that, but it's not working and my SQL knowledge isn't strong enough to troubleshoot. This is the error:
`PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "jobs.company_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT jobs.company_id, avg(jobs.level_of_interest) FROM "co...`

Comment: @Landfried: I've edited the example above - see if that works for you :-)

Comment: That's it! Thank you.